# kafka-consumer-groups.sh does not show all groups that KafkaTool does

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka-consumer-groups.sh does not show all groups that KafkaTool does, such as console-consumer-* and anonymous.* groups. I am looking at: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala
and:
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.java 
and I don't understand why exactly is it so, ie what's the crucial difference in a key or in a message from __consumer_offsets topic, which causes CLI to disregard such records, but sometimes I wonder if certain topic was recently opened for consuming, regardless of the fact if it was inside normally named consumer group, or not, and this seems to be not possible by using kafka-consumer-groups.sh?

Comment: Is kafka tool open source?

Comment: No, it is not open source. http://www.kafkatool.com/purchase.html

Comment: What command are you using to describe groups? Using `--zookeeper` will not show console consumer

Comment: kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server host:port --command-config client.properties --describe --group groupname         I use command config to define SSL properties.

Comment: I don't use `--zookeeper`

Comment: And if you combine that result with with using Zookeeper flag, what do you get? My point is that KafkaTool cannot possibly use any publicly accessible Kafka API to get its list of groups. I doubt it actually scans the consumer offsets topic

Comment: OK, if I issue kafka-consumer-groups against prod cluster via zookeeper, I don't get any groups, and from test cluster I get only some very small subset of groups, only 3 of them. So, if KafkaTool doesn't get these groups by scanning consumer offsets topic, then it must get them from zookeeper?

Comment: If you read over the source code of the group command, it doesn't start a consumer from the offsets topic either

Comment: But if I use zookeeper-shell.sh I don't see anything with `ls /consumers` on prod, and I see a lot of messages in consumer offsets topic, so I figured it reads it from there.

Comment: AFAIK, consumer groups that use bootstrap servers are maintained in memory by the controller broker.

Comment: The fact that the CLI returns so fast, there's no way it reads the whole offsets topic

Comment: OK, that's true. But how can I read the memory of controller broker directly, without messing something up?

Comment: You use the ListConsumerGroupResults class https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.java#L2930

Comment: Actually, that is not relevant. I am interested in consumer groups that kafka-consumer-groups doesn't return. This was comment to my latest comment, not to your post.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure. I cannot reproduce the problem because I see console consumer groups when I list from my cluster

Comment: OK, thanks, I can try that class, but as I said, this will I guess return me the same groups as kafka-consumer-groups.sh, and I am actually interested in magic performed by KafkaTool.

Comment: Hmm, I see console consumer groups only with KafkaTool.

Comment: As that magic is actually pretty slow, I am fairly sure that KafkaTools reads the offsets topic in order to list groups, unlike kafka-consumer-groups.sh, which is much faster.

Comment: You're welcome to use `kafkacat -C -b kafka:9092 -t _consumer_offsets -o earliest`